# Jquery click event on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.kat1 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat1:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07h.jpg);
    }

// here I have a code for .kat2,kat2 ... styles
#div {
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#div div').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var style = elem.css('background-image');
    if(/h\.jpg/.test(style)) {
      elem.css('background-image', style.replace(/h\.jpg/, '.jpg'));
    } else {
      elem.css('background-image', style.replace(/\.jpg/, 'h.jpg'));
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div">
        <div class="kat1 changing"></div> 
        <div class="kat2 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat3 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat4 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat5 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat6 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat7 changing"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem - when I click once div change bacground color but when I click second time on same icon then I cant change div background...

demo www.pluspon.com/kategorije.html

Comment: Replacement seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/FxFhv/.. view the file changing in firebug. Are you sure the `:hover` style is not confusing you?

Comment: Seems you sorted out the problem, just as I sorted out the reason: you added the `onclick` listener twice. When any div was clicked, the first listener changed the background and the other changed it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to have this functionality in JavaScript? An other option would be to use CSS classes to simplify the process:

```
$(function() {
  $('#div div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.kat1 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
}
.kat1:hover,
.kat1.active {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07h.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Your function toggles a CSS Class while CSS :active is an attribute. Two different things.

Comment: Thanks for your comment